# How to run multiple batch files with single External Tool in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, batch-file, external-tools

In Visual Studio, using External Tools, is it possible to have a tool set up to execute multiple .bat files?

I have two .bat files in my project directory and I currently have a tool for each of them set up, so I go up to Tools and select each one.  I was trying to find a way to run both .bat files at once without creating a third .bat file just to call those .bat files.

Each one individual has the Command pointed to the cmd.exe, and their Arguments as /C filename.bat

Is there a way to pass in both of the .bat files to have them run sequentially (or in parallel, I'm not picky) or will I need to create a third .bat file to point to each of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `&` chaining commands operator; or better yet the `&&` conditional chaining operator that only invokes the second command when the first one has successfully run (exit code is 0).

Try it first in the command line

```
 start cmd /c "so1 && so2"
```

if you have problems with competing quotes (the case when the commands themselves need to use quotes), you can also escape with `^` the `&` character

```
 start cmd /c so1 ^& so2
```

finally set your new external tool arguments to the syntax that better fits your requirements, probably `/c "so1 && so2"` will be enough.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thank you kindly.