# Visual Studio External Tool Arguments for multiple vbs files to debug HTA application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, vbscript, hta

I need to debug several VBS files that make up a HTA application.

I've searched the web and couldn't find the exact QA. This one about [How to run multiple batch files with single External Tool in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208311/how-to-run-multiple-batch-files-with-single-external-tool-in-visual-studio) and [How to debug IE9 HTA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397152/how-to-debug-ie9-hta) which *a silver bullet hasn't been found*.

This is where I'm stuck, I debug **main.vbs** and it references a `class cutils` which is in the file **utils.vbs**. And when I step over this line to instantiate cutils I get an error:

> Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Variable is undefined: 'cutil'

[image]

So I tried a few [External Tool Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76712d27.aspx) like comma separated files:

```
//nologo //X  "$(ItemPath), $(ItemDir)utils.vbs"
```

But that doesn't work. Is that possible, to specify multiple files?

Otherwise apart from copying all the classes into one file how can I debug the VBS files in Visual Studio? I've tried to attach VS debugger to mshta.exe however it does NOT get into debug mode, even with the standard `debugger` keyword doesn't halt code control:

```
function clickButton()
    debugger
```

So I am after a way to debug multiple VBA files with cscript.exe or even better attach to a mshta process to step through the code with debugger attached.

---

**Update 1:**

Following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/316491/495455 I tried creating a wsf file with all the references and using cscript.exe to debug:

```
<job id="IncludeExample">
   <script language="VBScript" src="main.vbs"/>
   <script language="VBScript" src="utils.vbs"/>
</job>
```

This starts off on main.vbs however it still fails to find the cutils class in utils.vbs:

[image]

---

**Update 2:**

So I renamed the .hta file extension to .html and that allowed me to open IE's Developer tools. For some reason pressing F12 in a HTA application doesn't allow you to use the Dev Tools.

When I do this, debugging is painful, the debugger can *seem* to find utils.vbs however, when I call the activate function in main.vbs it says it can't be found. Or more specifically main is not defined.

[image]

Comment: In update 1, are you running the debugger using the `wsf` file? I.e. `cscript.exe //nologo "test.wsf"`.

Comment: In update 1, I had the vbsDebugging.wsf file open and clicked Tools menu > cscript to debug it, VS then opened the "VBScript - script block" as per screenshot

Comment: Have you tried just running `cscript.exe //nologo "test.wsf"` from a command prompt outside of the debugger does it work or still error?

Comment: Sorry not at work for another 12hrs to check right now. I will try since VBScript is an interpreted language, not a compiled one so to rule out an issue with the debugger. Any other ideas mate?

Comment: I'd make sure that you define the "includes" in order they are used, so for example at the moment you define `main.vbs` before `utils.vbs` but you try and call `cutil` class in `main.vbs`. Reorder `utils.vbs` so it is defined before `main.vbs` in your list of scripts and try again. I don't think the debugger is the problem, I'd wager that the script will still fail when called outside the debugger.

Comment: Ahhh, of course, that may be what 'script block' alludes to. Will also check the hex code 0x800a01f4 in err.exe and see if the vbs files properties has that "Blocked" checkbox ticked

Comment: Just make sure `utils.vbs` doesn't reference something in `main.vbs` or you will end up with a circular dependency.

Comment: @Lankymart can you put your comment as an answer *define the "includes" in order they are used in the WSF file* - this did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42359052/visual-studio-external-tool-arguments-for-multiple-vbs-files-to-debug-hta-applic/42380126#comment71879530_42359052), the likely cause is the order of the scripts in the WSF file. Try arranging them so `utils.vbs` comes before `main.vbs` as it appears to have a dependency on the `cutil` class in `utils.vbs`.

```
<job id="IncludeExample">
   <script language="VBScript" src="utils.vbs"/>
   <script language="VBScript" src="main.vbs"/>
</job>
```